# printing result in TextView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I would like to have details about the digital signature and on the Internet I found this code that prints the values ​​of the signature using the `Log`. I would like to use a `TextView` so I wrote this code:

But when you open the Dialog,it crashes with a `NullPointerException` here

```
firma.append(""+c.getSubjectDN()+"\n");
```

Why? How can i fix it? I just want to print the result in the `TextView` instead Log...

Comment: c or its subjectDN is probably null, how are you creating that object, could cf.generateCertificate return null or an incomplete X509Certificate object ?

Comment: Seems there is some issue in certificate generation `c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input)` . Try to put a Log.d inside your all exception handling block with e.getMessage() and check if you getting any exception while trying to generate the certificate.

Comment: But if I instead of using firma.append use Log.d everything works properly without any crashes .. And 'This is the strange thing.

Comment: then try to print this `Log.d("","my TextView here "+firma);` and check if it is printing null .